# CORS Issues with Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Django

Tags: django, nginx, cors

I am running Nginx as my webserver to server the static frontend files and as a reverse proxy for my Django Server. The Problem is that i am having CORS Issues, when doing request from the frontend. My Design-Plan was to use the Apex Domain `example.com` for the frontend and all API Calls go to `api.example.com`.

I already did a tone of research and tried to catch OPTIONS request etc. but i still have CORS Errors. Also Django has the django-cors package installed and Axios is using `.withDefaultCredentials = true`. My current nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name $DOMAIN_HOSTNAME;
    root /var/www/example.com/dist;

    location /media {
        alias /var/www/example.com/media/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}

upstream djangoserver {
    server django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name $API_DOMAIN_HOSTNAME;
    

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://djangoserver;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
        proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    

        proxy_redirect off;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            return 204;
        }
    }
}
```

Also so no confusion is happening internally the nginx is serving on port 80, but its behind cloudflare which is establishing a https connection from client to cloudflares network. In the Django setting there is the domain configured:

```py
# Allowed hosts this django app is allowed to run on.
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    "localhost",
    "127.0.0.1",
    os.environ.get('DOMAIN_IP'),
    os.environ.get('FRONTEND_DOMAIN_HOSTNAME')
]


# Cors policy (allowed origins) options...
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "http://127.0.0.1" + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
    "https://127.0.0.1",
    "https://127.0.0.1" + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost" + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
    "https://localhost",
    "https://localhost" + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
    "http://" + os.environ.get('FRONTEND_DOMAIN_HOSTNAME'),
    "http://" + os.environ.get('FRONTEND_DOMAIN_HOSTNAME') + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
    "https://" + os.environ.get('DOMAIN_IP'),
    "https://" + os.environ.get('DOMAIN_IP') + ":" + os.environ.get("FRONTEND_PORT"),
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
```

Am i doing something wrong with my design or am i just missing something? I'm quite new to nginx configs.